# How do I modify this Google Colab to accept my own zipped file, and run the model on my own images?

Tags: python, file, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

here is the link to the google colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CwknSSXVtb-UBAw7Lm9slu_DgCO5M5wW

I'm having trouble linking my dataset to the code and running the model on it. I'm trying to adapt this notebook https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb to run it on my own dataset, but I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-14-542fb7cdb61e> in <module>()
      6     **datagen_kwargs)
      7 valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
----> 8     data_dir, subset="validation", shuffle=False, **dataflow_kwargs)
      9 
     10 do_data_augmentation = False #@param {type:"boolean"}

1 frames
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/keras_preprocessing/image/directory_iterator.py in __init__(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation, dtype)
    104         if not classes:
    105             classes = []
--> 106             for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    107                 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
    108                     classes.append(subdir)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/root/.keras/datasets/training_photos'
```

*if anyone could give me some advice on how to adapt the original google colab notebook to run on my own dataset (stored on my computer files) and get predictions, I'd be very grateful as I am new to this.*

Comment: Do you want to run it on google colab? or do you want to run it somewhere else? if running on google colab, you can upload your data somewhere and then download it in the colab notebook

Comment: @jakub I would like to train and test the model, convert it to TensorFlow Lite and then run it on my raspberry pi, to run the model on video feed from the pi camera :-)

Comment: @Swalkr I'm not sure that addresses their question entirely. You want to train the model on Google Colab, before running it on a raspi?

Comment: @AMC yes, exactly, apologies if I wasn’t clear enough earlier